# Paid taxes a year early

Tags: united-states, income-tax

I paid taxes for 2015 on income I earned in 2015, but didn't get paid for it until 2016. Now I have the 1099 for 2016. What should I do? Do I pay taxes for the income now and amend my old taxes? Or should I consider it already paid? Pros, cons?

There's not a lot of money involved.

Comment: 1099 implies USA

Answer (score 3):

1099's and other official tax forms are often reported to the IRS by the issuer, whether or not you include a copy in your return. You should not neglect to include this income in your 2016 return in an attempt to balance out the two tax years. It's up to you whether or not you feel like filing an amended 2015 return to recover over-payment of taxes from that tax year.

You have up to three years to [amend tax returns](https://www.irs.gov/uac/newsroom/irs-offers-tips-on-how-to-amend-your-tax-return) using form 1040X. Since you couldn't have furnished a 1099 for this when you filed your 2015 return (otherwise you wouldn't be in receipt of it for tax year 2016), I'm assuming you reported it simply as "Other Income" and therefore would have been [over] taxed your marginal rate on it.

From irs.gov:

> **When to amend a return.**  You should file an amended return if you need to correct your filing status, number of dependents, total income, tax deductions or tax credits. The instructions for Form 1040X, Amended U.S. Individual Income Tax Return, list additional reasons to amend a return.